# How to attach a cylinder to a hexagon

Tags: modeling, objects

How would I get a shape like in image?

[image]

Basically an hexagon with a cylinder merged but with the curve of the cylinder perfectly tangential to the two edges it is in contact with on the hexagon.

I'm coming from a SolidWorks background so maybe trying to be too exact.

Comment: Blender is definitely not made for this level of precision. You can snap meshes and stuff to various points like origins, other mesh faces & vertices, etc. Your best bet is using 2 meshes (hexagon & cylinder), snapping them together as close as possible then using a Boolean Modifier or joining them together into a single mesh.

Comment: Why not import the shape you want as an SVG first?  This will give you a more exact starting point, and then you just extrude the shape.

Comment: Will do, thanks

Answer (score 5):

There are ways to do it with Blender native tools, but non will be even vaguely similar to CAD procedures.

If you want a workflow as close to Solidworks as possible using Constraint based Skektches, you can look into experimental [CAD Sketcher addon](https://www.cadsketcher.com/).

Create a new sketch, and design an hexagon with the line tool from the toolbar.

[image]

Add equal length costraints and angle constraints until it is fully defined, then make the circle tangent to the two desired edges.

[image]